# angular change css files and make effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular

Now I have 2 css files (ltr.css/rtl.css) i have imported file as default in angular.json file or import it from index.html they working great,
but when load one as default in index.html and trying to change one to another by js in angular service the href changed but style not as i loaded it as default that like need to reload page or make refresh

html css tag

this is my code that make change css to another

```
initLayoutAlign(){
    this.translate.get('LANGALIGN').subscribe((align)=>{
        this.document.getElementById('style-bandle').setAttribute('href','assets/demo/default/base/style.bundle'+(align=='rtl'?'.rtl':'')+'.css');
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is condition issue --

just change this

```
this.document.getElementById('style-bandle').setAttribute('href','assets/demo/default/base/style.bundle'+(align=='rtl'?'.rtl':'')+'.css');
```

to

```
this.document.getElementById('style-bandle').setAttribute('href','assets/demo/default/base/style.bundle'+align+'.css');
```

This will point to `style.bundle.rtl.css` or `style.bundle.ltr.css`

Comment: thanks , but the condition works fine but i found that i  removed the css files from angular.json but after that  i don't re-serve angular to see the changes , so it's work good now but there is a second that css files are changing the web page is be with now has css just text